# remove tabs from string and attach it to another string php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi there I have some HTML that is treated like a string ,I format it in my Back End and need it to appear in front end formated as well

```
$var1 = 
'
        elseif( isset($_GET["view"]) && !empty($_GET["view"])  )
        {
            define("PAGE","VIEW_PAGE");

            require("VIEW/'.$data["page"].'/'.$data["page"].'.data.json.php");
            $view = json_decode( $viewDatabase );

            if( getIndexOfObjectHasElement($view,"id",$_GET["view"]) !== null ){
                $view = (array) $view[getIndexOfObjectHasElement($view,"id",$_GET["view"])];
            }
            else
            {
                header("location: '.$data["page"].'.php");die();
            }

        }
';

$var2 =
'
   if( !isset($_GET["view"]) && !isset($_GET["add"]) && !isset($_GET["edit"]) )
   {
      define("PAGE","MAIN_PAGE");
   }
   '.$var1.'
';
```

need the output

```
echo $var2;
```

to be

```
   if( !isset($_GET["view"]) && !isset($_GET["add"]) && !isset($_GET["edit"]) )
   {
      define("PAGE","MAIN_PAGE");
   }
   elseif( isset($_GET["view"]) && !empty($_GET["view"])  )
   {
         define("PAGE","VIEW_PAGE");

         require("VIEW/'.$data["page"].'/'.$data["page"].'.data.json.php");
         $view = json_decode( $viewDatabase );

         if( getIndexOfObjectHasElement($view,"id",$_GET["view"]) !== null ){
            $view = (array) $view[getIndexOfObjectHasElement($view,"id",$_GET["view"])];
         }
         else
         {
            header("location: '.$data["page"].'.php");die();
         }

    }
```

**without formating the code inside the variables something like `preg_replace` but I could not understand it**

Comment: https://www.ideone.com/QtUJRm

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that html removes the spaces and newlines you could try replacing all newlines with `<br>` and spaces with `&nbsp;`. 
You can do this in php with

```
$var1 = preg_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $var1);
$var1 = preg_replace("\n", "<br>", $var1);
```

If you also use tabs or other whitespaces in your formatting you should replace them with the corresponding expressions in html. For example for tabs this would give

```
$var1 = preg_replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $var1);
```

Comment: I am creating a page like a crude that create PHP page and need the created page to be formated you understand what I am doing

Comment: Not exactly, do you want to display the php code to a user or execute it? If you want to display it my solution should do, otberwise you dont need formatting since php ignores formatting when compiling.

Comment: The code after that is printed in a file to execute it later , I know that php will compile with no format but I need to format it for debugging later

Comment: How are you writing your strings to a file? Normally your spaces and tabs shouldn't disappear when writing a string to a file.

Comment: `include('file that include these variables specifc $var2');
   $myfile = fopen('file I created and want to write in', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite( $myfile, $var2 );
   fclose($myfile);`